# how to get HttpResponse key value and get the response from some url?

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I need to get a key value of `HttpResponse` from some URL and send the value again to the url to get some results through Restapi

```
resp = requests.get('https://someurl.io')
data = HttpResponse(resp)
return data
```

with this code i got a response like,

```
{"status":200,"result":{"postcode":"BN14 9GB","quality":1,"eastings":515087,"northings":105207,"country":"England","nhs_ha":"South East Coast","longitude":-0.36701,"latitude":50.834955,"european_electoral_region":"South East","primary_care_trust":"West Sussex","admin_ward":"Offington","ced":"Cissbury","ccg":"NHS Coastal West Sussex","nuts":"West Sussex (South West)","codes":{"admin_district":"E07000229","admin_county":"E10000032","admin_ward":"E05007703","parish":"E43000150","parliamentary_constituency":"E14000682","ccg":"E38000213","ced":"E58001617","nuts":"UKJ27"}}}
```

I have to send only the latitude and longitude value to some URL and get results. I would like to do this in rest api. I dont know how to get only latitude and longitude value and through the value how to get response from someurl.io.

Comment: You can obtain the dictionary of the result with `data.json()['result']`, and thus then construct a new dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a Python dictionary with `data.json()`, and then do some processing to construct a new dictionary, like:

```
resp = requests.get('https://someurl.io')
resp_data = resp.json()['result']
result_dic = {
    'longitude': resp_data['longitude'],
    'latitude': resp_data['latitude']
}

# ...
```

You can for example return the dictionary as:

```
return JsonResponse(result_dic)
```

and this will thus contain a dictionary with two keys: `'longitude'` and `'latitude'`. You can of course pass other values as well.

Comment: but i can get values only this command                                                                                                                                 return JsonResponse(result_dic['longitude'], safe=False)                                                                                it doesnot work if i give                                                                                                                     return JsonResponse(result_dic['longitude'], result_dic['longitude'], safe=False)   why??

Comment: @Divyaprabha: please don't return a non-dictionary as JsonResponse, there have been several hacks with this: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/ that is why `safe=...` is used here.

Comment: @Divyaprabha: no just `JsonResponse(result_dic)`, don't make it harder than it is.

Comment: TypeError
Exception Value: string indices must be integers got this error.. That's why I wrote like that.

Comment: @Divyaprabha: did you by any chance still use `data = HttpResponse(resp)`?

Comment: @Divyaprabha: you did not process that result right? That is the result of the view? It looks as if your did some indexing like `['some_value']` on a string, not on a dictionary (like `resp_data`).